# Does the dinic's algorithm work for bidirectional edge?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, max-flow

Ford-fulkerson algorithm does work for bidirectional edges with a slight modification.But I'm confuesd about dinic's algorithm.Is this algorithm works fine as well for bidirectional edges ?

Comment: What do you imagine the problem to be?

Comment: Sorry.I didn't get you.

Comment: it is basically the same as ford fulkerson's algorithm, isnt it?

Comment: Yeah take a long to understand this.BTW thanks to all.